# Feature request: how to get non-confusing lists (numbered as well as bulleted)?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

When typing a post, if you want to make a numbered list, this can be confusing when making lists for mathematical purposes, like the list of solutions of $x^2-3x+2=0$:

1. 1
2. 2

=> Does this mean $1$ and $2$ or $1 \times 1$ and $2 \times 2$?

At one side, this can be handled by the post author ((s)he can write the following instead):

1. $x_1=1$
2. $x_2=2$

... but it could also be handled by the website, like by using a special format for the numbers of the numbered list (put them in circles, squares, ...); even the bracket, as used by MS-Word, are clearer:

[image: MS-Word screenshot]

I believe that list formatting is shared over all StackExchange sites, but some sites do have their own formatting "rules" or features (like MathJax, here on the mathematics site).
Would it make sense to modify the display of numbered lists for the mathematical related StackExchange websites?

Comment: ? Why the downvote?

Comment: MathJax does not support the *list* or *enumerate* environments (here https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm#environments is a page that lists the supported environments) and nor does Markdown (which produces the lists you mention).  Your feature request probably needs to go on meta.stackexchange.com as it would affect all sites if Markdown is changed.

Comment: @postmortes: my question is not about MathJax, it's about the regular numbered list formatting.

Comment: @Dominique "MathJax does not support the list or enumerate environments (here onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/… is a page that lists the supported environments) and **nor does Markdown (which produces the lists you mention)**..." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Dominique Yes, I know.  It is not about MathJax.  No one has suggested that it is about MathJax.  It is about **Markdown**, which does not support the kind of lists you want.  Markdown.  Not MathJax.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I'm sorry. As my question contained MathJax and the first comment too, I was too focused on that. I understand your statement now.

Comment: As proposed, I wrote this question again as a general StackExchange question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396246/feature-request-make-numbered-list-formatting-less-math-unfriendly

Comment: Also, addressing your first comment:  downvotes on meta do not count towards your XP, and are generally used to indicate either agreement or disagreement.  I would take an upvote to mean "I agree that this is a feature which should be implemented," and a downvote to mean "I do not believe that this feature should be implemented."

Comment: @postmortes I would actually caution *against* putting feature requests like this on Meta.  Here, upvotes and downvotes don't really matter.  On Meta, XP is actually tracked, and posting a feature request for a feature that no one seems to want can lead to downvotes and question bans.  It is probably better to leave feature requests like this local, and then allow a moderator to apply the [tag:status-review] tag when/if it seems like there is community consensus.

Comment: You can write `1. )`. You can use `-` for a bullet & have any label you want. Granted not automatically numbered.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did not know that!  Thank you for the information :)